# How do I validate a user input and show my output after typing in a text box, using tkinter in python?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, user-input

I am currently building a Python-based application, which converts inches to feet, fahrenheit to celsius, etc. I want the converted answer to appear right after the user finished typing, without a button or clicking. I tried using the validate(input) function, but it's not working well.

[Here is a pic of my code of converting inches to feet:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9YsZ.png)

Is there a better way to write this function? Please let me know.

Comment: Please add your code in the question.

Comment: It seems there are errors in your `validate` function, also Tkinter validation is not supposed to be used to change other entries (validation is used to ensure that entry contains only characters that you allow), instead you should use `textvariable` attribute and [`StringVar` object](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-a-stringvar-object-in-an-entry-widget-in-tkinter). If you want to get an answer to your question, you will need to [add your code to the question](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c).

Comment: Use `tk.DoubleVar()`

Comment: There's a link to my image shown above, do you see it?